# Calculate difference between two time records

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I found many questions similar to mine but not quite the same, and nothing I found in them helped me so here is new one.

Expected output: Difference between one time record and previous one if the User is the same.

Sample table:

```
+-------+--------+-------------------+------+   
| RowID | User   | Godzina_transakcji| Diff |   
+-------+--------+-------------------+------+   
|    1  | AAA    | 14:23:03          |      |   
|    2  | AAA    | 14:23:57          |      |   
|    3  | AAA    | 14:25:03          |      |   
|    4  | BBB    | 03:37:23          |      |   
|    5  | BBB    | 03:39:21          |      |   
|    6  | BBB    | 05:23:11          |      |   
+-------+---------+------------------+------+
```

So query should for row 1 give 0, for for 2 give =14:23:57-14:23:03 and so on.

So far I have something like this (based on @Tom Collins answer in other question) but for some reason it gives [Error]
[image: 1]

```
 SELECT tblTemp2.RowID,
       tblTemp2.User,
       tblTemp2.Godzina_transakcji,
       Nz(Dmax("Godzina_transakcji", "User", "(Godzina_transakcji <" & [Godzina_transakcji] &
                                             ") and (User = '" & [User]
                                                        &"')"), 0) - [Godzina_transakcji]  AS Diff
FROM   tblTemp2;
```

What am I doing wrong in this one? Also, on another step I will have to take account of passing midnight in between.

**Conclusion:**
If anyone will look for similar problem here is code that worked for me. Thanks Gustav, you are a God!

```
SELECT 
    tblTemp2.RowID,
    tblTemp2.User,
    tblTemp2.Godzina_transakcji,
    Format((    Select TimeValue(T.Godzina_transakcji) 
                From tblTemp2 As T
    Where tblTemp2.RowID = T.RowID + 1  And tblTemp2.User = T.User ) - TimeValue([Godzina_transakcji]), "hh:nn:ss") As Diff
FROM
   tblTemp2;
```

Comment: What is the data type of *Godzina_transakcji*? Please see table definitions.

Comment: In all tables it date/time, but maybe it's because its imported from txt file it doesn't import it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you times stored as text. You must convert to true time to compare directly:

```sql
SELECT tblTemp2.RowID,
       tblTemp2.User,
       tblTemp2.Godzina_transakcji,
       Nz(Dmax("Godzina_transakcji", "tblTemp2", "(TimeValue([Godzina_transakcji]) < #" & [Godzina_transakcji] & "#) and (User = '" & [User] & "')"), #00:00#) - TimeValue([Godzina_transakcji])  AS Diff
FROM   tblTemp2;
```

To use the ID:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblTemp2.RowID,
    tblTemp2.User,
    tblTemp2.Godzina_transakcji,
    (Select TimeValue(T.Godzina_transakcji) 
    From tblTemp2 As T
    Where T.RowID = tblTemp2.RowID + 1 And T.User = tblTemp2.User) - TimeValue([Godzina_transakcji]) As Diff
FROM
   tblTemp2;
```

Comment: Hmm, now error has changed. Now it's "the microsoft database engine cannot find the input table or query "User".

Comment: It is your tables, so I guess you don't have a table User. Why not use the table you are testing with?. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Uhh sorry, must have been too late to see that... I've added Format(..., "hh:nn:ss") to whole difference calculation to get result in the same format as Godzina_transakcji. But I wondering is there a way to return 0 or null if User changes between records?

Comment: As you have sequential IDs, why not use these? See extended answer, please.

Comment: Made small modification - switched argument in WHERE and now it does excacly what it should. Thank, you are a GOD!

Comment: One more question regarding to that. When there is blank field as a result of this query what does it contains? Because I've tried to refer to it as Null and it didn't work

Comment: I would believe it to be _Null_ but, if not, how about a zero-length string: `""`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it was zero-length string as you pointed `""`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `DMax` and `DLookUp`, although on a large dataset you'll probably get performance issues:

```
SELECT RowID, User, Godzina_transakcji,
Nz(DMax("RowId","tblTemp2","User='" & [User] & "' and RowId<" & [RowId]),0) AS Prev_RowID,
DLookUp("Godzina_transakcji","tblTemp2","User='" & [User] & "' AND RowId=" & [Prev_RowId]) AS Prev_Godzina_transakcji, 
DateDiff("s",[Prev_Godzina_transakcji],[Godzina_transakcji]) AS Diff_in_sec
FROM tblTemp2;
```

I've used the `RowId` instead of the time in the lookup with the assumption that your data is stored sorted by the time.

The `DMax` gets the previous `RowId` based on the `User`:

```
Nz(DMax("RowId","tblTemp2","User='" & [User] & "' and RowId<" & [RowId]),0) AS Prev_RowID
```

The `DLookUp` get the previous time based on the user and previous `RowId`:

```
DLookUp("Godzina_transakcji","tblTemp2","User='" & [User] & "' AND RowId=" & [Prev_RowId]) AS Prev_Godzina_transakcji
```

You then calculate the difference using `DateDiff`:

```
DateDiff("s",[Prev_Godzina_transakcji],[Godzina_transakcji]) AS Diff_in_sec
```

This will give you the time difference in seconds.

Comment: Goal is to create tool that will handle bigger data range than Excel so anything that is low in performance I must discard at the beginning.