# How to upend query to a table as new column in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

As a follow up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184049/calculate-difference-between-two-time-records) I wanted to go further with it and do other calculations based on my Diff.

Sample table:

```
+-------+-------+--------+-------------------+------+------+------+   
|   ID  | RowID | User   | Godzina_transakcji| Diff | Diff2| Diff3|   
+-------+-------+--------+-------------------+------+------+------+   
|    3  |    1  |   AAA  | 14:23:03          |      |      |      |   
|    8  |    2  |   AAA  | 14:23:57          |      |      |      |   
|    11 |    3  |   AAA  | 14:25:03          |      |      |      |   
|    2  |    4  |   BBB  | 03:37:23          |      |      |      |   
|  893  |    5  |   BBB  | 03:39:21          |      |      |      |   
|    5  |    6  |   BBB  | 05:23:11          |      |      |      |   
+-------+-------+---------+------------------+------+------+------+
```

Working code:

```sql
    SELECT 
        tblTemp2.RowID,
        tblTemp2.User,
        tblTemp2.Godzina_transakcji,
        Format((    Select TimeValue(T.Godzina_transakcji) 
                    From tblTemp2 As T
        Where tblTemp2.RowID = T.RowID + 1  And tblTemp2.User = T.User ) - TimeValue([Godzina_transakcji]), "hh:nn:ss") As Diff
    FROM
       tblTemp2;
```

So I thought the best way will be append my tblTemp with Diff, and here is where it started to hit the fan.
When I tried to change query to "Make table" my Access freezes for up to 10min. When I try to use Update query I get error about "Operation must use an updatable query.".
So my question is: what is best way to do this having in mind that next fields will be simple ifs based on calculated Diff?

For example idea about Diff2 is to check if value of hours in Diff is bigger than 4.

Edit: Hope, now it's more precise and goes along with rules :)

Comment: A question should be complete in itself.  You can refer to other questions for clarification, but your question should have sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why save to table? Just do calcs in query or report.

Comment: I need to have it saved because data from this database will be used in pivot table in excel. Main goal is to create tool for basic users to analyze data bigger than max excel range, so I thought that Access will be easiest to implement. So now I'm stuck trying to convert those diff calculation from excel to Access.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem which is a good thing.  I ran your sql against a table.  Most likely  access is bugging because you are running sql with a subquery (complicated) against a query(more complication).  turning your previous queries into a table(s) as soon as access bugs for no good reason should solve the problem.  In other words start turning queries into tables sooner.

Comment: Yea, that was my thought: too many queries depending on each other will cause problems. Right now this query calculating diff gets data from temp table so it's first step after table creation. And still it freezes when I try to change this select query into make table or make another query that save results of this one into new temp table.